# No text message notifications on Android 4.4.2

Tags: sms, 4.4-kitkat, notifications

I just upgraded my Note 2 with 4.4.2, and since then I stop receiving notifications from text messages, voice mails and emails. I do not see the LED blinking on any text messages or voice messages.

Everything is active in my LED indicator, everything in my "messagings notification settings" is enable, all my volume are at 100%

What can I do to fix thiS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your SMS:

Check if the notifications in "messaging" is turned off. Maybe you, someone or an app turned it off (untrusted app). Turn on the app and make sure the "show notifications" is checked.

Go to: Settings -> More -> Application Manager -> All -> Messaging

You can do the same process for emails and voice messages.

Now, make sure all the services are ON for emails and voice messages.

Go to: Settings -> More -> Application Manager -> Turned off

Check if any emails or voice services are off. If these are off (you prob have rooted your phone) then you should be able to turn them back on.

You might need to reboot for these.

Answer (score 0):

sorry but I have to ask, did you restarted your phone and checked if that fixes the problem, if so then go to System Settings->Notifications and check there if everything is set there.

Comment: I did reboot but I can't find "System Settings->Notifications". I checked in my sounds and led and everything is checked.

Comment: did you switch to hangouts? also try to check setting->apps->messaging options there

Comment: I cant find this option ... is it under connection? my device? accounts? or more?

Comment: I think after the update it will be under more and it's called application manager, but make sure you are not using hangouts as default sms app

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas.
From your home screen, go to Settings, then choose Sounds, then choose Volume then look at the slider for Notifications.  If it's all the way to the left, then your notification volume is off, slide it to the right and that might fix the problem

Also, I was told that there was a problem in the 4.4.2 build and only the "whistle" sound works.

Last, Go to settings. then choose sounds, then look for the banner that reads, "Samsung Applications"  there are 4 choices under it.  (Call Messaging Email Calendar) Pick Messaging.  Make sure Notifications is checked.  Select Ringtone must be "default ringtone".

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Apps  -> All (scroll horizontally), search for Messaging, and check Show Notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue on my Google Pixel 3XL. Click on "Shortcut to Prevent Ringing" and turn it off.
All of my sounds started working after that.

Answer (score -1):

Try going to 
sounds and notifications >
Application notifications >
Messages >
Unblock

Answer (score -3):

You could as well uninstall your phone launcher. 
Most of these launchers might interfere with your app notifications by listing them as junk.

All the best.

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion? It is hard to establish a relation between the problem and the suggested solution here, not to mention, removing the only launcher can render the phone useless to OP and frighten them.